# Auto-detect proxy settings on network

Tags: windows-server-2003, networking, proxy

I am having problems trying to run web browser software on the local network through the proxy.
When running off the profile drive which is on a network share, the system is unable to auto-detect proxy settings.
When running off the local C drive, the browsers are able to correctly autodetect the settings.
The error from the browser is about it being unable to fetch the proxy configuration file.
Is this some form of authentication preventing it retreiving the settings when running of the network location?
PS. Would this be better off on superuser?

Answer (score 1):

Browsers get their proxy settings 3 ways:

1. Manually set - eg in connection settings: proxy.example.com port 8080
2. [Pac file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config) - www.example.com/proxy.pac
3. [WPAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Proxy_Autodiscovery_Protocol) where the proxy is set by DHCP or DNS

If it's a Pac file -  2. - on your network, try and manually browse to the proxy.pac file.  If you can't get to it this is what you need to address.

Let us know your results.

Comment: 4th way - set by group policy!